# Handling arithmetic expressions in shell scripting

Tags: shell

Kindly tell me that is it necessary to use "expr" keyword.

EG:-

```
 echo `expr a*b`
```

And where we can simply handle arithmetic expressions using simple arithmetic operators.

EG:-

```
echo a*b
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using bash shell.Is first method mentioned in question cannot be used for evaluating arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second form will almost surely never do what you want. In Bash, you have a built-in numeric expression handler, though:

```
A=4; B=6; echo $((A * B))
```

Answer (score 15):

In a Posix shell you can evaluate expressions directly in the shell when they are enclosed in

```
$(( ... ))
```

So:

```
a=12
b=34
echo $(($a + $b))
```

And although this wasn't always the case, all Posix shells you are likely to encounter will also deal with:

```
echo $((a + b))
```

This all happened because, a long time ago, the shell did not do arithmetic, and so the external program `expr` was written. These days, `expr` is usually a builtin (in addition to still being in /bin) and there is the Posix `$((...))` syntax available. If `$((...))` had been around from day one there would be no `expr.`

The shell is not exactly a normal computer language, and not exactly a macro processor: it's a CLI.  It doesn't do inline expressions; an unquoted `*` is a wildcard for filename matching, because a CLI needs to reference files more often than it needs to do arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do arithmatic using `$(())`

```
echo $((2*3))
```

results in 6