# Need help in solving an expression in shell

Tags: unix

How to calculate X power Y in the unix shell script where value of Y is being supplied by a loop eg. Y=1 to 5. It means I  would like to calculte (X^Y)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A, it's not a general help desk. For questions like this about basic shell commands, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I've voted to close this question, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling arithmetic expressions in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586513/handling-arithmetic-expressions-in-shell-scripting)

Comment: OK, this is not "shell" but it's much faster than shell: `awk -v m=5 'BEGIN{for(i=0; i<m; i++) print 2^i}'`

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you could do:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do printf "$((2 ** $i))\n"; doneprintf "$((2 ** $i))\n"; done
2
4
8
16
32
```

Many shells however do not support `raise to power` operation and in
such situations you need to use bc:

```
$ for i in $(seq 5); do printf "%s\n" "$(echo "2 ^ $i" | bc)"; done
2
4
8
16
32
```